Is $C = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \:|\: \textbf{1}^T(x)_- \leq \frac{1}{2}\textbf{1}^T(x)_+ \}$ a convex set?
We define $(x)_+ = \textbf{max}\{0, x\}$ and $(x)_- = \textbf{max}\{0, -x\}$, so $x = (x)_+ - (x)_-$.
Let $\textbf{1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a column vector whose entries are $1$. The $\textbf{max}$ function is applied element-wise between two vectors.
Is $C = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \:|\: \textbf{1}^T(x)_- \leq \frac{1}{2}\textbf{1}^T(x)_+ \}$ a convex set?
I tried using the definition of convex combinations as follows:
Let $x$, $y \in C$ and $z = \theta x + (1-\theta)y$ where $0 \leq \theta \leq 1$. From the definition and the convexity of $y = \textbf{max}\{0, x\}$:
$$(z)_+ = \textbf{max}\{0, z\} = \textbf{max}\{0, \theta x + (1-\theta)y\} \leq \theta \: \textbf{max}\{0, x\} + (1-\theta) \: \textbf{max}\{0, y\} = \theta (x)_+ + (1-\theta)(y)_+ \:\:\:\:\: \textbf{(1)}$$
$$(z)_- = \textbf{max}\{0, -z\} = \textbf{max}\{0, \theta (-x) + (1-\theta)(-y)\} \leq \theta \: \textbf{max}\{0, -x\} + (1-\theta) \: \textbf{max}\{0, -y\} = \theta (x)_- + (1-\theta)(y)_- \:\:\:\:\: \textbf{(2)}$$
From $\textbf{(2)}$
$$\textbf{1}^T(z)_- \leq \theta \textbf{1}^T (x)_- + (1-\theta) \textbf{1}^T(y)_- \leq \theta \frac{1}{2}\textbf{1}^T (x)_+ + (1-\theta) \frac{1}{2}\textbf{1}^T(y)_+$$
In the last step, I cannot use $\textbf{(1)}$ because the direction of the inequality sign is different.
What I would like to ask is that am I on the correct path? If yes, how can I proceed? If no, what should be the right approach to proving the convexity of the given set?
Thank you.

$\textbf{1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a column vector whose entries are $1$. The $max$ is applied element-wise between two vectors. I've just edited the post.

Using
$$
 (x)_+ = \frac 12 (|x| + x) \, , \, (x)_- = \frac 12 (|x| - x)
$$
we have for $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$:
$$
\begin{align}
\phi(x) &:= \textbf{1}^T(x)_- - \frac{1}{2}\textbf{1}^T(x)_+
\\
&= \frac 12\sum_{j=1}^n  (|x_j| - x_j) - \frac 14\sum_{j=1}^n  (|x_j| + x_j) \\
&= \frac 14 \sum_{j=1}^n (|x_j| - 3 x_j) \, .
\end{align}
$$
It is straight-forward to verify that $t \mapsto |t| - 3t$ is a convex function. (It is piecewise linear with a non-decreasing slope.)
It follows that $\phi$ is a convex function on $\Bbb R^n$, and therefore is
$$
 C = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \phi(x) \le 0 \}
$$
a convex set.
Examples: In one dimension, $C$ is the set of nonnegative real numbers. In two dimensions, $C$ is a sector (image created with the Desmos Graphing Calculator):


Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $C$ be the set
$$C \quad = \quad \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n; {\bf{1}}^{\top}x_+ \ge 2\cdot({\bf{1}}^{\top}x_-) \}.$$
It [the set $C$ that is] is indeed convex.
We first note the following:
Claim 1: A vector $y$ is in $C$ iff the inequality
${\bf{1}}^{\top}y \ge {\bf{1}}^{\top}y_-$ holds.
[Indeed, Claim 1 follows from noting that
${\bf{1}}^{\top} y = {\bf{1}}^{\top}y_+ -  {\bf{1}}^{\top}y_-$.
Plugging in the inequality ${\bf{1}}^{\top} y_= \ge 2 \cdot({\bf{1}}^{\top} y_-)$
yields Claim 1.]
Claim 2: Let $x'$ and $z'$ be two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Then the inequality
${\bf{1}}^{\top}(x'+z')_- \le {\bf{1}}^{\top}x'_- + {\bf{1}}^{\top}z'_-$.
[To see Claim 2, work component-wise.]
Let $x,z$ be vectors in $C$ and for any $\lambda \in [0,1]$ let $y
= \lambda x + (1-\lambda)z$.  To show that $C$ is convext it suffices
to show that $y$ is in $C$.
Let us set $x'=\lambda x$ and $z'=(1-\lambda)z$. Then $x'$ and $z'$
are both in $C$. Then:
$${\bf{1}}^{\top} y_- \mathop{\le} _{\text{Claim 2}} {\bf{1}}^{\top}x'_- + {\bf{1}}^{\top}z'_-$$
$$ \mathop{\le}_{\text{Claim 1}}  {\bf{1}}^{\top}x' + {\bf{1}}^{\top}z'$$
$$={\bf{1}}^{\top}(x' + z') = {\bf{1}}^{\top} y,$$
or in particular,
$${\bf{1}}^{\top} y_- \le {\bf{1}}^{\top} y.$$
The result follows by Claim 1.

However, note that Claim 1--or anything close enough to Claim 1--does not hold if $C$ were instead, say $C_{1/2}$ where:
$$C_{1/2} \quad = \quad \Big\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n; {\bf{1}}^{\top}x_+ \ge
\frac{{\bf{1}}^{\top}x_-}{2} \Big\}.$$
[Here the factor of $2$ for $C$ as defined near the beginning of this post and in the OP, is replaced by a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ for the $C_{1/2}$ defined here, hence the name $C_{1/2}$ for the variable.] And indeed: It [the set $C_{1/2}$] is not convex. Let $n=2$ and then the set $C_{1/2} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ works out to
$$C_{1/2} \quad = \quad \Big\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2;  \ ((1,1)^{\top}(a_+,b_+) \ \ge \ \frac{(1,1)^{\top}(a_-,b_-)}{2}\Big\}.$$ Consider $x_=(5,-9)$ and $z=(-9,5)$. Then $x$ and $z$ are both in $C$ but $y=(-2,-2)$ $=.5x+.5z$ is clearly not.
I close this with a further question:
Question: Suppose we were to define, for some positive scalar $\lambda$, the set $C_{\lambda}$ as follows:
$$C_{\lambda}\quad  = \quad \Big\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n; {\bf{1}}^{\top}x_+ \ge
\lambda \cdot {\bf{1}}^{\top}x_- \Big\}.$$ For what [positive] values of $\lambda$ is $C_{\lambda}$ convex? We have already shown that $C_{\lambda}$ is convex if $\lambda=2$ and $C_{\lambda}$ is NOT convex if $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$, but what about other positive values of $\lambda$.
HINT: $C_{\lambda}$ is convex for positive $\lambda$ iff $\lambda$ satisfies the inequality $\lambda \ge 1$.

Interesting generalization. Since $\textbf{1}^T(x)+ \geq \lambda \textbf{1}^T (x)- \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2} \textbf{1}^T ((\lambda-1)|x| - (\lambda+1)x) \leq 0$ as shown by @Matin R, the set $C$ is indeed convex if $\lambda \geq 1$.

@tcm thank you. Look at MartinR's diagram above, and see what the shape would be if $\lambda=1$, and then for say $\lambda= \frac{1}{2}$.

Essentially, if each term in the sum of absolute values has a non-negative coefficient, it's sum of convex functions, still convex, and the associated level set is convex

Yes, it is convex.
Each function $x\to (x_i)_--\frac 1{2}(x_i)_+$ is convex, and we take a positive linear combination of those, again convex.
Your set is just a sub level set, hence convex.
